# rails admin column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-admin

I'm getting a column does not exist when editing a user in rails admin.  The relationship between sales and users is user has_many :sales, and sale belongs_to buyer and another belongs_to for seller, written out like

`belongs_to :seller, :class_name=>User, :foreign_key=>:seller_id`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  column sales.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales"  WHERE "sales"."user_id" = 14
                                             ^
: SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales"  WHERE "sales"."user_id" = 14):
    1: = rails_admin_form_for @object, :url => edit_path(@abstract_model, @object.id), :as => @abstract_model.param_key, :html => { :method => "put", :multipart => true, :class => "form-horizontal denser", :data => { :title => @page_name } } do |form|
    2:   = form.generate :action => :update
```

I tried editing the config file for the model (initializers/rails_admin) to not show anything concerning sales on the show page.  I did this by adding just a few test fields (and leaving out anything to do with sales) to the `list do`, `show do` and `edit do` blocks for the User model.

I'm not too sure what to edit so that rails admin doesn't try to look for a user id within a sales table.

Any ideas and especially answeres are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `foreign_key` on the `has_many`/`has_one` association.

Check out the Rails Docs:

> :foreign_key
>
> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the
>   name of this class in lower-case and "_id"
>   suffixed. So a Person class that makes a has_many association will use
>   "person_id" as the default :foreign_key

Comment: No problem! Glad you got that sorted out.