# Using two has one relationships to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, has-one

I'm trying to find the best way to model a game in relation to teams.

The end goal is to be able to call things like:

```
@game.winner
@game.loser
@team.games
```

The first two relations are working, but the games one is not.  Using has_many (see below), I get `ERROR:  column games.team_id does not exist` which I would normally work around by using whatever the equivalent to `:foreign_key => winner_id`, but how can I have it checkout both `winner_id` and `loser_id`?

Is the only option to create a method in the teams model like so:

```
def games
  won = Game.where(:winner => id)
  lost = Game.where(:loser => id)
  won + lost
end
```

So far what I'm doing is:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :winner, class_name: "Team"
  has_one :loser,  class_name: "Team"
end


class Team
  has_many :games
  # or something that actually works
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873011/rails-admin-column-does-not-exist

Comment: Nope, mine is that, but I want two foreign keys

Comment: But actually might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307581/rails-model-has-many-with-multiple-foreign-keys

Comment: I'd do something similar as that answer, but write it as an OR condition scope instead of joining the two results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say much about the problem.  But I think you are working too hard. If a team can play several games and a game includes more than one team, then you you need a many to many relation.  This requires a third table, and best practice is a `has_many :through` relation.  It will look something like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, through: assignment
  has_one :winner, class_name: 'Team', through: :assignment, order: 'score DESC'
  has_one :loser,  class_name: 'Team', through: :assignment, order: 'score ASC'
end

class Team
  has_many :games, through: :assignment
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Now you have the winner and loser attributes, but you don't need to roll your own method to count games for a team.  Just say `team.games.count`  and similarly `game.teams` is the teams assigned to the game.

Comment: So I have to add a migration for the join table?

Comment: Well, you really want to generate a model, not just a migration.  `rails g model Assignment game:references team:references`